# Unable to get selected value for multiselect field added to product video form - Magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento2

I am developing an extension similar to product video

```
Product > Catalog > Images And Videos
```

I need a multi-select field but unable to get the selected values after form save. 
It shows only last selected value as selected. It seems there is an issue to store the selected multi-select field values. To replicate the issue you can add any multi-select field to product video form and try to save the details.

If anyone has done like this or have any idea, please share.